# Can I combine multiple Leaflet menus into one?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I've based a map off of this tutorial: https://datavizforall.org/leaflet-maps-with-google-sheets.html

My map can be viewed here: https://hamsci.org/get-involved
The github repo and Google spreadsheet, adapted from the tutorial, can be accessed by clicking the "code" and "data" links, respectively, in the lower right-hand corner of the map. The relevant geojson files are in the "geometry" folder of the repo.

I have one geojson file that combines all of the eclipse paths, and individual geojson files for each eclipse path. By following the template, I can create a menu for each eclipse path by duplicating the Polygon spreadsheet.

My question is this: Is there a way I can set up a single menu to display eclipse paths such that you can click a checkbox for each date, similar to the example polyline menu? In other words, can this template be manipulated to create such a menu for multiple polygon files?

Comment: Follow-up: Is there an easy way to convert these polygons to polylines? The template is well set up for displaying those....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround: I uploaded the individual eclipse paths to mapshaper.org and used the -lines command to convert the polygon outlines to polylines, then uploaded those instead and used the Polylines menu from the template for the eclipse paths. This doesn't let me include shading, but it does get things onto the map. Note that the resulting polyline files have .json file endings, not .geojson.